# setting the fourth decimal place in a number to 1 or 0

Tags: c#, math, numbers, decimal

In my windows based app I have made a units conversion from metric to imperial and back again. This works in theory except if I was to do the following

-set default units to imperial

-update numbers (now lets say my number is equal to 1000 in)

-set default units to metric

-update numbers (now lets say my number is equal to 25400 mm)

-set default back to imperial

-update numbers (here's the problem)

--at this point my numbers will not update because my code doesn't convert if the number is already in these units (I can show the code if you want but it is not needed for my question) which is needed so I figure the easiest way to overcome this bug is to change the fourth decimal place in my numbers to either 0 for metric or 1 for imperial but I can't just say

```
number += 0.0001 or number -= 0.0001
```

because during the conversion I could get a number like 3452.823591384023840583 but I will take this number and only show the first three decimal places `3452.823` so for this example I want to take my number and change the fourth decimal place (because it isn't shown anyway) and change it to either 0 or 1. So here is what I want...

take a number lets use 1.234567 and change that fourth decimal place (the 5) and change it to either 0 or 1 what ever one I want, lets use 0 right now. So now I will have a number that is 1.234067. Once I have this new number I want to be able to check that fourth decimal place in a if statement to see if it is either a 0 or a 1 so something like

```
if(number.getFourthDemialPlace() == 1) DO STUFF
```

if further explanation is needed or code, I will be glad to give it, thanks.

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to come up with a really ugly hack to workaround a fairly simple problem.  There are probably multiple ways to solve this without resorting to some sort of "magic" placeholder value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do, and this is the easiest way in my opinion. (Not dealing with a lot of calculations, etc). Convert the number into a string (using `ToString( )` method). Then, replace the fourth character after decimal point with 0/1. Then, convert it back to back to the number. You can check the fourth decimal place by doing the same...

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use formatting to deal with your actual issue...

To extract particular digit most straightforward ways is to multiple/divide by `10^x` to shift digit you are interested in into ones place, cast to `int`/`BigInteger` and than get result of `% 10`:

```
 ((int)(value * 10000) %10 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just keep the units in one type? And do conversion on modifiers 
I will show you an example to let you know what I mean:

```
public enum UnitType
{
    Feet = 0 ,Meters = 1
}

public Length
{
    public Length(decimal lenInMeters)
    {
        _lenInMeters = lenInMeters;
    }

    private decimal _lenInMeters;
    private decimal ConvertToMeters(decimal feet)
    {
        //do conversion
    }

    private decimal ConvertToFeet(decimal meter)
    {
        //do conversion
    }

    private void ChangeByFeet(decimal feetChange)
    {
        _lenInMeters + ConvertToMeters(feetChange);
    }

    public void Change(decimal amount, UnitType units)
    {
           switch(units)
           {
              case(UnitType.Meters):
                  _lenInMeters+=amount;
                  return;
              case(UnitType.Feet):
                  _lenInMeters+=ConvertToMeters(amount);
                  return;
              case(default):
                  throw new ApplicationException("not supported type");
           }
    }

    public decimal InFeet
    {
        get
        {
            return ConvertToFeet(_lenInMeters);
        }
    }

    public decimal InMeters
    {
        get
        {
            return _lenInMeters;
        }
    }
}
```

This way you won't have to yoyo between conversions and what you are trying to do is not opaque like the way you originally suggested.